# Excel графики, как объединить данные в графике

Tags: excel

Имеется два набора данных, значение - время
Как построить в excel график, чтобы на графике значения отмечались точно? 
Как в источниках данных использовать и значение X и Y? На скриншоте ниже видно, что точки по горизонтальной оси (времени) совпадают, хотя в данных это не так, естественно потому, что в источнике данных графика можно указать только один набор данных

[Документ](https://vk.com/doc207618250_496339670?hash=d0075c04d44b5ccd0a&dl=885d6f064a0eefb399) с скриншота

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы не путаться в понятиях "график", графиком останется графическое отображение, а данные в таблице - **Г** и **О**.

**Вариант1** Данные для горизонтальной оси  - принять время **О** (в этом диапазоне шаг времени не меняется). Пульс **Г** нужно интерполировать (вычислить промежуточные значения по имеющимся дискретным данным). Т.е. дополнительная таблица для **Г**, в которой время такое же, как в **О**, пульс - интерполированные значения. При этом точки двух графиков будут на одной линии по вертикали.

Вариант сравнительно непрост в реализации и может вносить некоторую погрешность в данные **Г**

' -------------------------------

**Вариант2** Горизонтальная ось должна отображать все точки времени двух графиков. Шаг шкалы времени - наибольший общий делитель.  Да, таблица получится многострочная. Уменьшить количество строк можно, если убрать точки времени, которые отсутствуют и в **Г**, и в **О**. Формула определения точек времени:

```
=НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(($B$3:$B$6;$D$3:$D$6);СТРОКА(A1))
```

Данные пульса для нужных точек времени вычислить формулами:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(B:B;F3);ИНДЕКС(A:A;ПОИСКПОЗ(F3;B:B;));НД())

=ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(D:D;F3);ИНДЕКС(C:C;ПОИСКПОЗ(F3;D:D;));НД())
```

Почему *НД()*? Дело в том, что на графике в точках времени, которых нет в таблицах **Г** или **О**, не нужно ничего показывать. Но если оставить ячейки пустыми, он будут восприняты, как нули, и графики будут "падать" в ноль. А вот ошибка *#Н/Д* при построении графика игнорируется.

Значения ошибки можно скрыть с помощью условного форматирования: выделить столбцы *G:H*, формат при выполнении условия - белый шрифт, формула УФ:

```
=ЕНД(G1)
```

(на рисунке для сравнения: УФ задано только для столбца G)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]